# Как скролить Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

У меня есть canvas, на котором я рисую граффик и он у меня выходит за границы. Я пробовал добавить ScrollViewer  но он не работает ://

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не знаю, у меня точно такой же ScrollViewer и все работает. Если вы спросите, как я сделал, что у меня работает, я спрошу: "как вы сделали, что у вас не работает?".

Comment: Я пишу приложение для работы с графиком изменения цен, сам график я рисую в виде точек на canvas и когда цена растет то график выходит за границы вверх а так в права, мне нужно сделать так чтоб я мог просматривать весь график скроля его в лева и вправо и в верх вниз

Comment: TickGraph.Children.Add(elipse); - так я добавляю на canvas точку.

Comment: `<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <Canvas  x:Name="TickGraph">

                    </Canvas>
            </ScrollViewer>`